# G++ Building Sample Boost Code

Tags: c++, boost, g++

I am trying to build a boost sample code from their website at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/gil/example/dynamic_image.cpp

On Ubuntu 14.04 and G++ 4.8.

Code below:

```
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/dynamic_image/any_image.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg_dynamic_io.hpp>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::gil;

    typedef boost::mpl::vector<gray8_image_t, rgb8_image_t, gray16_image_t, rgb16_image_t> my_images_t;

    any_image<my_images_t> dynamic_img;
    jpeg_read_image("test.jpg",dynamic_img);

    // Save the image upside down, preserving its native color space and channel depth
    jpeg_write_view("out-dynamic_image.jpg",flipped_up_down_view(const_view(dynamic_img)));

    return 0;
}
```

Compile command:

```
g++ -o dynamic_image.o dynamic_image.cpp -Iboost -Iimagelib/jpeg-6b -Iimagelib/libpng-1.6.13
```

Produces Errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/vector:64:0,
                 from kboost/boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg_io_private.hpp:24,
                 from kboost/boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg_io.hpp:32,
                 from kboost/boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg_dynamic_io.hpp:31,
                 from dynamic_image.cpp:20:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:117:7: error: ‘std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type& std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_get_Tp_allocator()’ cannot be overloaded
       _M_get_Tp_allocator() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:113:7: error: with ‘std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type& std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_get_Tp_allocator()’
       _M_get_Tp_allocator() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:547:7: error: ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin()’ cannot be overloaded
       begin() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:538:7: error: with ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin()’
       begin() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:565:7: error: ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end()’ cannot be overloaded
       end() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:556:7: error: with ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end()’
       end() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:583:7: error: ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_reverse_iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::rbegin()’ cannot be overloaded
       rbegin() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:574:7: error: with ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reverse_iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::rbegin()’
       rbegin() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:601:7: error: ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_reverse_iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::rend()’ cannot be overloaded
       rend() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
```

I am fairly certain the problem has nothing to do with sample code, so what am I doing wrong? My best guess is I am using the wrong library or the compiler is configured incorrectly...

**Update**
Adding the -std=c++11 flag fixed my error. Now I am receiving the following errors:

```
In file included from kboost/boost/config.hpp:61:0,
                 from kboost/boost/mpl/aux_/config/msvc.hpp:19,
                 from kboost/boost/mpl/aux_/config/adl.hpp:17,
                 from kboost/boost/mpl/aux_/adl_barrier.hpp:17,
                 from kboost/boost/mpl/bool_fwd.hpp:17,
                 from kboost/boost/mpl/bool.hpp:17,
                 from kboost/boost/mpl/aux_/na.hpp:17,
                 from kboost/boost/mpl/vector.hpp:19,
                 from dynamic_image.cpp:18:
kboost/boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg_io_private.hpp:37:45: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘boost::gil::detail::jpeg_read_support_private<Channel, ColorSpace>::is_supported’
     BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bool,is_supported=false);
                                             ^
kboost/boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg_io_private.hpp:38:52: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘boost::gil::detail::jpeg_read_support_private<Channel, ColorSpace>::color_type’
     BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(J_COLOR_SPACE,color_type=JCS_UNKNOWN);
                                                    ^
```

G++ Version

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: try using `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x`

Comment: Thanks! That got me over the first set of errors. Updated question with more errors :(

Comment: That's strange. You can try `#define BOOST_NO_INCLASS_MEMBER_INITIALIZATION` before including boost headers, but g++ 4.8 should have no trouble with in-class initialization of a `static const bool`. Try `g++ --version` to check if you're using the right compiler?

Comment: Added g++ version output to question. Adding `-DBOOST_NO_INCLASS_MEMBER_INITIALIZATION` took care of those errors, but more errors remain which I do not believe should be errors either.

Comment: Not reproducible here with any -std= and any g++. Which version of boost  are you using?

Comment: I also can't reproduce your errors: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/l0yyWjqvcRlYIMRz

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will use that tool and re-evaluate my environment.